# Search in specific folder on SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-search

how can I search in specific folder of a list in SharePoint 2013 with the API?

A lot of tries of me failed :(

```
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='*B*+AND+List:DocumentLibList'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

or

```
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='*B*+AND+path:"http://localhost/sites/MainSite/DevSite/DocumentLibList"'&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'
```

I need a fulltext search for a specific folder of the DocumentLibList. Optional with filtering properties of the documents - if possible.

Thanks in Advance for any idea(s)! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an asterisk by the end of the path string? Also, you could try using the site: filter passing the absolute path to the folder as a value.

```
http://localhost/_api/search/query?querytext='*B*+site:"http://yourserver/yourlibrary/yourfolder"'
```

The SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool would be helpful in this trial and error process:

https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/